# Get current action

Tags: jquery, html

I have a wrapper div, in side that div i have a div, On click of that div i have to show a message. My problem is that i can rendering its id on runtime which is unique but all have common class.

Now my markup is inside a loop,Say if the html markup is rendering 10 times it means, I have 10 buttons.

When i click any one of theme it appears for all the 10dives.

How to solve this please help me.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML markup and the jQuery code?

Comment: If you put in some sample HTML and script to show the problem it might make it more clear and allow other people to give a solution that works for your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain of your question. I tried to extract the relevant information. Here is an example of using jQuery to handle the click event of a 'button' divs inside a parent div. If this is not quite what you are asking, please provide additional information.

http://jsbin.com/ahive3/9/edit

Hope this helps.

Bob